# In Typescript, is a Float64 the same as base64 encoded characters (to make a byte array)?

Tags: arrays, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to make a new type in typescript that is a byte array, consisting of base64 encoded characters, as I don't think there is a type already existing that does this. Upon searching for typescript documentation, the only encoded type that seems similar is 'Float64' in typescript. Is this the same thing? I thought floats were numbers, but I want this byte array to represent strings.

Comment: What's wrong with string to represent a string?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, I just happen to need to represent a 'bytearray' with base64 encoded characters in Typescript

Comment: My point is that if what you have is a sequence of characters (like 'aGVsbG8='), which happen to represent base64 encoded bytes ([104, 101, 108, 108, 111], which are the bytes of the string 'hello' when encoded in ASCII), a string is all you need: `string base64EncodingOfHelloAsciiBytes = 'aGVsbG8=';`)

Comment: Float64 will likely be a 64 bit floating point number - not what you're after.